# Delete all lines without @ textmate regex

Tags: regex, textmate

I have a huge file that I need to filter out all lines (comma delimited file) that do not contain an email address (determining that by @ character).

Right now what I have is this to find all lines containing the @ sign:

```
.*,.*,.*@.*,.*$
```

basically you have 4 values and the 3rd value has the email address.

the replace with: value would be empty.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try replace `^[^@]*$` with nothing. Alternatively, `grep` the file with your regex and redirect the result into a new file.

Answer (score 4):

You have about 10 different ways to do this in TextMate and even more from the command line.  Here are some of the easier ways...

**From TextMate:**

1. Command-control-t, start typing some part of the command "Copy Non-Matching Lines into New Document", use @ (nothing else) for the pattern.
2. Same as above, except the command you're looking for is "Distill Document / Selection"
3. Find and select an @ symbol. Then do the same as the above but search for the command "Strip Lines Matching Selection/Clipboard".  You may not have it as I may have developed this one myself.

**From the command line:**

Type one of the following commands, replacing FILE with the filename, including the filepath if it's not in your current working directory.  The filtered content can be found in FILE-new.

1. *Using egrep:* `egrep -v '@' FILE > FILE-new`
2. *Using sed:* `cat FILE | sed -e "/@/D" > FILE-new`

For both of the above, use `diff` to see what you accomplished: `diff FILE{,-new}`

That should probably do, I'm guessing...